# Reverse array in C?

Tags: arrays, string

Hi guys I just cant seem to reverse my array, my syntax looks ok and my logic seems fine but the FOR function is just not iterating through.  This function is meant to reverse arrays, mainly strings.    and  n = length of the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char, int);

int main()
{
    char a[100];
    gets(a);

    reverse(a, strlen(a)-1);

    printf("%s\n",a);
    getchar();
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void reverse(char ar[], int n)
{
    char c;
    int i = 0;
    printf("n = %d" , n);
    for ( i = 0; i >= n ; i++){
        c = ar[i];
        ar[i] = ar[n];
        ar[n] = c;
        printf("Processed");
        n--;}

}


/*
if (begin >= n)
return;

c          = *(x+begin);
*(x+begin) = *(x+n);
*(x+n)   = c;
offs = x++;
printf("Begin = %d   ,  n = %d, offs = %p  \n", begin, n, offs);
reverse(x, ++begin, --n); */
```

Comment: I've added an answer, but... why don't you run your code in a debugger when it doesn't work? That should be the first thing to do before asking on Stack Overflow. Also, use proper indentation. Sorry to say but the current style is... er, crappy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition with the loop variable is wrong, it should test for less-than, not for greater-than (since you seem to want to go from 0 to `n`).

`i >= n` should be `i < n / 2`.

Comment: @EricJablow if n > 0 then it won't even enter the body of the OP's for loop.

Comment: @Matt That's not what Eric was talking about. I had a mistake in my answer which I have now fixed by removing it.

Comment: It's possible to use two variables in a for-statement: `for(size_t lower = 0, upper = n; lower < upper; lower++, upper--)`.  The intent is then cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

As well as the logic bug already pointed out by @H2CO3, your function prototype is wrong - change:

```
void reverse(char, int);
```

to:

```
void reverse(char *, int);
             ^^^^^^
```

Note that if you compile with warnings enabled (e.g. `gcc -Wall ...`) the compiler will point out such mistakes and thereby save you a lot of time and effort.

Comment: Yay, that's another one.

Answer (score 0):

This is O(N) performance. Actually you only perform N/2 iterations

```
void reverseArray(char[] arr) {
        int start = 0, end = strlen(arr) - 1, tempVal;
        for (; start < end; start++, end--) {
            //swap start & end location
            tempVal = arr[end];
            arr[end] = arr[start];
            arr[start] = tempVal;
        }
    }
```